# Find a ratio between 2 lines.

Tags: geometry

I need to find a ratio between $BO$ and $OX$.

[image]

The ratio $BY$ to $YC$ is $4 : 1$. $AX$ and $XC$ are equal.

Probably, I have to use Theorem of Thales about parallel lines that intersect an angle. But I don't know where to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Menelaus's lemma in triangle $BCX$ we get:

$${\frac{CA}{AX}}.{\frac{XO}{OB}}.{\frac{BY}{YC}}=1$$

since ${\frac{CA}{AX}}=2$ and ${\frac{BY}{YC}}=4$ we get
$${\frac{BO}{OX}}=8$$

Comment: Cool. Thanks! This looks good. I didn't know that theorem. Is there a way to find the answer using Theorem of Thales about parallel lines that intersect an angle?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 8:1.

Connect OC.  Let $\triangle{XOC}$ be 1 unit.  Then $\triangle{AOX}$ will be 1 unit.  $\triangle{AOC} = 2$ units.  Now, $\triangle{YOC}:\triangle{BOY} = 1:4$, and $\triangle{AYC}:\triangle{BAY} = 1:4$.  So $\triangle{AYC}-\triangle{YOC}:\triangle{BAY}-\triangle{BOY} = 1:4$.  This means $\triangle{AOC}:\triangle{BAO} = 1:4$.  $\triangle{BAO} = 8$ units since $\triangle{AOC} = 2$ units.  Now $\triangle{ABX} = 9$ units, so $\triangle{BOC} = 8$ units.  Compare $\triangle{BOC}$ and $\triangle{COX}$.  They have the same height, but different bases, with area ratio of $8:1$.  This means the ratio of their bases, $BO:OX = 8:1$.